# Como grabar un elemento en html con js o jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, cordova

Tengo un incoveniente, necesito grabar un elemento div que con contiene un video y un elemento canvas que genera una mascara como muestro a continuacion [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí], eso es lo que quiero grabar, ya he probado la libreria de RecordRTC.js, esto es para cordova, uno de sus plugin permiten grabar la pantalla pero tampoco me sirvio, no he podido encontra los medios para lograr mi objectivo, espero que me puedan ayudar